# prevent conversion of carriage return "\r" to "\n"

Tags: python, subprocess, carriage-return

I have following code in t.py:-

```
import time

for i in range(1,100):
    print(f"{i}% \r",end='')
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

it count 1 to 99 in single line like this:-

[image]

So when I execute following code, I expect the same

```
import subprocess as sb
import sys

lol = sb.Popen('python t.py',stdout=sb.PIPE,shell=True,text=True)

while True:

    l = lol.stdout.read(1)
    if not l and lol.poll() is not None:
        break
    if(l == '\n'): # for checking
        print(" it should've been \\r") # this should not happen

    sys.stdout.write(l)
    sys.stdout.flush()

print("done")
```

But this code prints 1% to 99% in all separate line. like this:-

```
1%  it should've been \r

2%  it should've been \r

3%  it should've been \r

4%  it should've been \r

..... i have skipped this part .....

99%  it should've been \r

done
```

So i added a little if statement

```
    if(l == '\n'):
        print(" it should've been \\r")
```

the above if statement shows that somehow '\r' might be converted into '\n' which I don't want.

Comment: `lol = sb.Popen("python t.py", stdout=sb.PIPE, shell=True)`?

Comment: Hm. `lol.stdout.reconfigure(newline='')` seems to solve the translation issue, but output never seems to be flushed.

Comment: @CristiFati I get `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes` without `text=True` and with decode(), it prints nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's in the documentation: (https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> "If encoding or errors are specified, or text (also known as
>   universal_newlines) is true, the file objects stdin, stdout and stderr
>   will be opened in text mode using the encoding and errors specified in
>   the call or the defaults for io.TextIOWrapper."
>
> "For stdout and stderr, all line endings in the output will be
>   converted to '\n'. For more information see the documentation of the
>   io.TextIOWrapper class when the newline argument to its constructor is
>   None."

Remove the text=True flag to avoid this behavior. When you do that, note that the stuff you read from stdout is now bytearrays and not strings, and you'll have to deal with them accordingly.

The following implementation of t.py and the main script achieves what you want.

t.py:

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(1,100):
    print(f'{i} \r', end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Main script:

```
import subprocess as sb
import sys

lol = sb.Popen('python3 t.py',stdout=sb.PIPE,shell=True)

while True:


    l = lol.stdout.read(1)

    if not l and lol.poll() is not None:
        break

    print(l.decode("utf-8"), end="")

print("done")
```